# Loop dependency analysis: can this loop be parallelised?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am studying for our final exam, our prof gave us some exercises with the answers to practice. Pretty sure his solution is wrong here... can someone confirm/deny?

SUPPLIED QUESTION: Can we parallelize the following loop? If yes, do it. If not, why not?

```
a[0] = 0;
for( i = 1; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = a[i-1] + i;
```

(prof) SUPPLIED ANSWER: Yes, we can, if we realize that:

```
a[0] = 0
a[1] = a[0]+i = i
a[2] = a[1] + i = 2i
a[3] = 3i
```

(me) MY REASONING: If you follow the output this doesn't seem to hold:

```
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 0 + 1
a[2] = 1 + 2 = 3
... etc ...
```

Am I right that my prof is wrong? Or am I going crazy?

Comment: You are right that the supplied answer is incorrect. (Sorry about the earlier comment, I mixed up your answer with the professors).

Comment: Actually, your professor is right. That's why this is a great question for exam - and completely absurd in practical context. 

When number of parallel threads equals n, i will stay at initial value for all threads (i=1). 

That is what he meant by:
a[3] = 3i

but, to have expected value when a[i-1] you would use locks (or other control mechanism) that makes complete problem absurd. I'm posting this as comment since have no idea what openmp is. The catch could be in specific way for loop works in that language, like [for each] is quite different in C++ and C#.

Comment: Is the *"SUPPLIED ANSWER"* supplied by you or your professor?

Comment: The correct formula for `a[i]` when you realize that the loop can be rewritten is `i*(i+1)/2`. And yes, written this way, the loop can be parallelized.

Comment: "SUPPLIED ANSWER" is my professor, I've edited it to make it more clear now... wait so sorry which is it? Getting conflicting answers here

Answer (score 0):

Your professor probably confused the 'i' with another variable outside the loop.

It would work for:

```
j = ...;
a[0] = 0;
for( i = 1; i < n; i++)
   a[i] = a[i-1] + j;
```

That said, you can find a closed formula for `a[i]=a[i-1]+i`, but it involves a bit more mathematics. In this case it's:

```
a[i] = (i^2+i)/2;
```

In general, it could get a lot more complex, like this closed formula for the fibonacci series:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/how-to-prove-that-the-binet-formula-gives-the-terms-of-the-fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Whomever supplied this answer:

```
a[0] = 0
a[1] = a[0]+i = i
a[2] = a[1] + i = 2i
a[3] = 3i
```

is wrong, as substitution does not work that way.

The loop in question is the simplest example in which flow dependencies (aka "true" dependencies) can be located: `a[i]` is always written "before" it is read, hence a "read-after-write hazard". Flow dependencies impose asymmetric ordering.